# Whats the best way to convert array of hashes data to specific graph format data

Tags: ruby, hash, backslash, gsub, amcharts

I have an array of hashes returned from the below map function. I'm trying to populate data for a graph (I'm using AM Charts), which takes data in a specific format mentioned below-

**Sample structure of a company record:**

```
1.9.3p327 :073 > Company
 => Company(id: integer, name: string, contact_no: integer, email_id: string, website: string, fax_no: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, divisions_count: integer) 

@all_companies = Company.all
```

**Map function:**

```
@all_companies = @all_companies.map {|each_company| { Country: each_company.name, Visits: each_company.divisions_count} }
```

**Output format of above query:**

`[{:country=>"Samsung", :visits=>8}, {:country=>"Natraj", :visits=>2}, {:country=>"Tupperware", :visits=>5}, {:country=>"Transcen", :visits=>0}, {:country=>"camlin", :visits=>0}]`

**Graph data input format:**

```
  var chartData = [{
      country: "USA",
      visits: 4025
  }, {
      country: "China",
      visits: 1882
  }, {
      country: "Japan",
      visits: 1809
  }, {
      country: "Germany",
      visits: 1322
  }]
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p327. I need to convert my output array to the specific graph format. I try going about the same through the following steps:

```
  1.9.3p327 :070 >     @all_companies = @all_companies.to_s.gsub(":","")
 => "[{country=>\"Samsung\", visits=>8}, {country=>\"Natraj\", visits=>2}, {country=>\"Tupperware\", visits=>5}, {country=>\"Transcen\", visits=>0}, {country=>\"camlin\", visits=>0}]" 
1.9.3p327 :071 >     @all_companies = @all_companies.gsub("=>",": ")
 => "[{country: \"Samsung\", visits: 8}, {country: \"Natraj\", visits: 2}, {country: \"Tupperware\", visits: 5}, {country: \"Transcen\", visits: 0}, {country: \"camlin\", visits: 0}]" 
1.9.3p327 :072 > puts @all_companies
[{country: "Samsung", visits: 8}, {country: "Natraj", visits: 2}, {country: "Tupperware", visits: 5}, {country: "Transcen", visits: 0}, {country: "camlin", visits: 0}]
 => nil 
1.9.3p327 :073 >
```

Now when I'm trying to display the data in my graph, I'm getting the below syntax error:

```
var chartData = [{country: &quot;Samsung&quot;, visits: 8}, {country: &quot;Natraj&quot;, visits: 2}, {country: &quot;Tupperware&quot;, visits: 5}, {country: &quot;Transcen&quot;, visits: 0}, {country: &quot;camlin&quot;, visits: 0}]
```

The syntax error from the Firebug console now points to **&quot** in the above data.

Any work-arounds that could get me through the last step so that I can get the desired graph format?

### Question updated

I need the data in following format:

```
  var chartData = [

      {
          country: "Samsung",
          visits: 8
      },
      {
          country: "Natraj",
          visits: 2
      },
      {
          country: "Tupperware",
          visits: 5
      },
      {
          country: "Transcen",
          visits: 0
      },
      {
          country: "camlin",
          visits: 0
      }

      ]
```

Comment: Please add correct final output.

Comment: d.danailov - Question updated, it now shows the desired correct final output.

Comment: May I know why is the question downvoted and there's an upvote to close this question ?

Comment: Dear All, I've updated my question and the question title. Hope the question is more clear now. If so, I would appreciate if you could undo your close vote option.

Comment: Just rewrite your question. Show what you have and what you want. Nothing else.

Comment: oldergod - based on your original answer, I actually did that.  I think my question now should be comprehesible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917707/amcharts-integration-with-ruby-on-rails-using-data-from-the-database-to-populat).

This is what I do to overcome the **&quot syntax error**.

**In the controller**:-

```
def company_division_stats
    @all_companies = @companies_data = Company.all 

    @specific_details = @all_companies = @all_companies.map {|each_company| { country: each_company.name, visits: each_company.divisions_count} } 
    #@all_companies = @all_companies.to_s.gsub(":","")
    #@all_companies = @all_companies.gsub("=>",": ")

    respond_to do |format|
      unless @all_companies.nil?
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @specific_details, status: :created } #in the browser url would be:- localhost:3000/company_division_stats.json
      end
    end
```

**In the view**:-

```
var chartData = <%= @all_companies.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not printing your value. The console is only displaying it, double quotes are escaped.
Otherwise how would you know where my string: "my "string" what" ends?

If you just do

```
puts @specific_details.to_s
```

you will not see those double quotes escaped.

Comment: oldergod - I get your point now. Thanks. I've updated my question and the question title. Kindly check.

Comment: oldergod - +1 for pointing out that the backslashes in `"[{country: \"Samsung\", visits: 8}, {country: \"Natraj\", visits: 2}, {country: \"Tupperware\", visits: 5}, {country: \"Transcen\", visits: 0}, {country: \"camlin\", visits: 0}]" ` needn't have to be separately removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ***I need to convert my output array to the specific graph format.***

Do this using [**`Awesome Print`**](http://rubydoc.info/gems/awesome_print/1.1.0/frames) Rubygem -

```
require "awesome_print"

hsh = [{:Country=>"Samsung", :Visits=>8}, {:Country=>"Natraj", :Visits=>2}, 
       {:Country=>"Tupperware", :Visits=>5}, {:Country=>"Transcen", :Visits=>0}, 
      {:Country=>"camlin", :Visits=>0}]

ap hsh,{:index => false}
```

**output**

```
[
    {
        :Country => "Samsung",
         :Visits => 8
    },
    {
        :Country => "Natraj",
         :Visits => 2
    },
    {
        :Country => "Tupperware",
         :Visits => 5
    },
    {
        :Country => "Transcen",
         :Visits => 0
    },
    {
        :Country => "camlin",
         :Visits => 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Country, Visits shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: @boddhisattva see now!!

Comment: babai - Thanks for your suggestions. I'm sorry, thanks to oldergod I figured out that the backslash is not there anymore when I do a `puts @all_companies` from my console. Please see my updated question title and the updated question wrt the current issue I'm facing in getting input data for the graph in the appropriate format. Please bare with me for any inconvenience

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the pretty_generate and for awesome print gem. I didn't know something like pretty_generate existed earlier. I think it would be quite useful going forward. Thanks.